# NSArray filter using NSPredicate, comparing dates

Tags: objective-c, filter, nsarray, nsdate, nspredicate

I have a `Person` entity where the attribute `date_of_birth` is declared as NSString. If I have an array of 'Person' instances and I need to filter them down to only those whose `date_of_birth` is less that 25/11/2005 I am using a predicate whose format when NSLogged is:

```
FUNCTION(date_of_birth, "yyyy_MM_dd_dateFormat") <[cd] CAST(154575908.000000, "NSDate")
```

where `yyyy_MM_dd_dateFormat()` is a category method on NSString that returns the string instance as a date.

I am not getting the expected results. Am I doing something wrong, and what is the bit where it says `CAST(154575908.000000, "NSDate"` and is that valid?

UPDATE: changing the `date_of_birth` attribute type to NSDate is not an option at the moment due to the size, maturity and complexity of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates are best represented by `NSDate`, which implements inequality via `earlierDate:` and `laterDate:` methods. These answer the earlier/later date between the receiver and the parameter.

Your conversion method probably looks something like this ...

```
// return an NSDate for a string given in dd/MM/yyyy
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    return [formatter dateFromString:string];
}
```

The array can be filtered with a block-based `NSPredicate` that uses `NSDate` comparison...

```
NSDate *november25 = [self dateFromString:@"25/11/2005"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Person *person, NSDictionary *bind){
    // this is the important part, lets get things in NSDate form so we can use them.
    // of course it would be quicker to alter the data type, but we can covert on the fly
    NSDate *dob = [self dateFromString:person.date_of_birth];
    return date_of_birth == [november25 earlierDate:dob];
}];

// assumes allPeople is an NSArray of Person objects to be filtered
// and assumes Person has an NSString date_of_birth property
NSArray *oldPeople = [allPeople filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I am in a position where changing the Attribute type for date of birth is not an option. The project is very large and doing so would make a lot of stuff incompatible with each one another. I therefore have to deal with doing the filtering at the Array level as i am doing. Will be slower than having the attribute type as nsdate and doing the actual compare during the fetch I know, but this is the planned approach as of now.

Comment: I have had a look at my category method, the dates returned are nil, so I think that is where I have the problem..

Comment: what is type is that date_of_birth attribute?

Comment: by type I mean class. E.g NSString, or NSDate. This is with regards to core data hence my use of the word "attribute"

Comment: Please see edit.  I thought the attribute was already an NSDate, but the idea doesn't require that you change the data.  Just change to NSDates when doing logic on the array.

Comment: That is what I am doing :)

Comment: Not sure what the other code in the project is doing, but from what's posted, I see a scalar `<` operator.  That isn't going to make sense on anything but scalar values, like NSTimeIntervals.  The suggestion I'm making is to convert to NSDates and use NSDate inequality methods.

Comment: using `<` or `>` or `==` including others all work with NSPredicate when comparing NSDates. Let me test my changes and let you know. Thanks for the consistent help.

Comment: I had been trying to make use of a function on the actual core-data search instead of the results. Seeing that I could only convert the string dates to NSDate in after retrieval, I ended up comparing the strings themselves. That was luckily possible because of the way the date strings where formatted. Using your function on the array result would have taken ages to return a result because I have a large dataset. I tried it on a small dataset and it worked. But on my actual data it crashed after a few minutes (used up all the memory).

Answer (score 0):

Here, person date is type of NSDate.

NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@",person.date];

list=[list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate2];

But in case you saved with NSString type , than you need to cast comparison date into string than use like instead of >=

Comment: I'm sure I stated that I need all Person entities with birthdays before  25/11/2005. Comparing string values will not work for that

Comment: What is the type of entity you declared for Person  ? is that NSString OR  NSDate ?

Comment: 'Person' is the Entity name. All the details are in the question if you didn't go through it all.

Comment: you can't do with declaring date_of_birth as NSString. You need to set an attribute of type NSDate.

Comment: It is very much possible using FUNCTION(a, b) in an NSPredicate at the NSArray level. I have managed to get it to work by fixing my NSDateFormatter date format. Please be sure of your responses before updating here.